# matching the keys and replacing the values of the keys that matched

Tags: regex, perl, hash

TEST.txt

```
name     a  b  c  d
car      1  2  0  7
tram     7  8  9  5
bus_db   1  6  3  8
cari
busi_db
```

OUT.txt

```
name     a  b  c  d
car      1  2  0  7
tram     7  8  9  5
bus_db   1  6  3  8
cari     1  2  0  7
busi_db  1  6  3  8
```

I have a file as shown in TEST.txt wherein there are few keys that dont have values. I want to match the keys which dont have the values and put the same values of the keys that matched. The sample output is as shown.

EDIT: I have tried a longer procedure to seperate the keys with and without values in different files and then compare those files along with the extra "i" and append the values. I am not getting the desired output using this procedure

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: will there always be the "i" before the first "_" or at the end of the word if there is no "_" ?! Can explain your search pattern in words?

Comment: @tuxtimo : Yes their will always be "i" attached with the keys which dont have value. So i want to search for i along with the keys present along with the values.

Comment: @PLB i have tried a longer procedure to seperate the keys with and without values in different files and then compare those files along with the extra "i" and append the values. I am not getting the desired output

Comment: This is actually a very simple task... I will not write your script for you, but here are links to tutorials/examples for all the things you will need: - File parsing and output: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlfile.htm - String matching: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm - Perl hashes: http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/ (These are just some high ranking google hits... take the hint!)

Comment: Ok so you insert existing values on empty words... How do you select which values to insert? Your example looks random to me, except for some "resemblance" in the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis program appears to do what you require. It expects the source data file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

<>;

my %data;
my @keys;

while (<>) {
  my ($key, @values) = split;
  if (@values) {
    $data{$key} = \@values;
    push @keys, $key;
  }
  else {
    (my $newkey = $key) =~ s/i(?![a-z])//i;
    my $values = $data{$newkey};
    $data{$key} = [ @$values ];
    push @keys, $key;
  }
}

my $format = "%-7s%3s%3s%3s%3s\n";
printf $format, qw/ name a  b  c  d /;
for my $key (@keys) {
  printf $format, $key, @{ $data{$key} };
}
```

**output**

```
name     a  b  c  d
car      1  2  0  7
tram     7  8  9  5
bus_db   1  6  3  8
cari     1  2  0  7
busi_db  1  6  3  8
```

Comment: Is their a line of code which can be added to the above code which will delete the line which didnt have the matching key?? for example "tram" from the above output???

Comment: No. That is quite different problem with a different solution

Comment: ya i just found some solution for that... I have been using this code for so many cases and i found one problem that the code doesnt work if their is a key without a value which has "i" but that isnt present in the keys which have values. For example if test.txt have an extra key at the end named "scootyi". The output will be blanked if this is the case. But i was trying to change the code to print scootyi in the output with no values but i wasnt succesful. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  This assumes that the empty keys all end with either "i" or "i_db", and that the i must be removed to get the filled key.  If that is not true, the line `$other_key =~ s/i(?=(_db)?$)//g;` will have to be changed to match whatever you are looking for.  Also, I have left the file I/O for you to do.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $header = <DATA>;
#throw away the first field name, as it will be used as the hash key
my (undef,@fields) = (split /\s+/, $header);
my %hash;

#read in the file.
while (<DATA>)
{
    my @row = split /\s+/;
    for (0..$#fields)
    {
        $hash{$row[0]}{$fields[$_]} = $row[$_+1];
    } 
}

#find cases that don't have data and fill them in.
foreach my $line (keys %hash)
{
    foreach (keys %{$hash{$line}})
    {
        unless (defined $hash{$line}{$_})
        {
            my $other_key = $line;
            #Uses a lookahead assertion to match but not delete "_db"
            $other_key =~ s/i(?=(_db)?$)//g;
            if (defined $hash{$other_key}{$_})
            {
                $hash{$line}{$_} = $hash{$other_key}{$_}
            }
        }
    }
}

#Print the output.
print $header;
foreach (keys %hash)
{
    #Uses a hash slice to get all of the values at once.
    print join (" ",$_, @{$hash{$_}}{@fields})."\n";    
}

__END__
name     a  b  c  d
car      1  2  0  7
tram     7  8  9  5
bus_db   1  6  3  8
cari
busi_db
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first get the data into Perl. You'll open the file, and read it into a hash splitting on the first whitespace. I don't care to split `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` into separate data since it makes no difference in the program:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use autodie;

 open INPUT, "<", "TEST.txt";
 my %array;
 while my $line (<INPUT>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $data) = split /\s+/, $line, 2;
    $array{$key} = $value;
 }
```

This will give us the following:

```
$array{car} = "1   2   0   7";
$array{tram} = "7   8   9   5";
$array{bus_db} = "1   6   3   8";
$array{cari} = "";
$array{busi_db} = "";
```

Now, something you ***haven't*** explained: How do you know if a null array member *matches* a non-null array member. How do I know that `cari` *matches* `car` and `busi_db` *matches* `bus_db`? Is it the `i` appended to the end, but before a possible `db` suffix? Are their other things we should know?

Once you figure it out, getting them to match is pretty simple:

```
$array{busi_db} = $array{bus_db};
```

Then, it's a simple matter of printing them out.

```
 # Go through array and make "null" members match
 while my $key (sort keys %array) {
    if (not $array{$key}) { #Ah! a null array member!
        $matching_key = find_matching_key($key);
        $array{$key} = $array{$matching_key};
    }
 }

# Print them out
while my $key (sort keys %array) {
    print "$key = $array{$key}\n";
}

sub find_matching_key {
   # Here be dragons....
}
```

The question is that `find_matching_key` subroutine. You figure out what makes two separate keys match, and fill in the details.

By the way, according to your sample data, the null members come after the non-null ones. If this is always a true condition, there's no need to separate the *read* loop from the *merge* loop. Unfortunately, you didn't say whether this is true or not.

Nor, did you specify if I have to print the array in the same order as it was read in. I could have kept a list of keys, and kept them in order. I didn't because it would complicate the logic, and you didn't specify it.

---

Notice the low ranking of your question, and the fact that people are marking it for closing. This is because you basically said: *"I have this problem, solve it for me"*. You also didn't give enough details for a solution either. As I said, you talked about *matching keys*, but didn't specify what you mean.

Comment: I am very sorry for the incomplete question that have posted. I will keep everything in mind for my further conversation. And thank you for the detailed explaination